# How to get Mobile Broadband modem (ZTE K3370-Z) work?

Tags: internet, modem, mobile-broadband, zte

I am a die hard Ubuntu user. Few days back I installed 12.04 and purchased a Vodafone modem (ZTE K3770-Z).

When I try to make a mobile connection, I am *able to connect* to the network as indicated by the symbol on the top and constant light of the modem. But **I am not able to access any websites, software centre, etc.**

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing [Vodafone Mobile Broadband Manager (Betavine Connection Manager)](http://developer.vodafone.com/labs/opensource/linux-connection-manager/broadband-connection-manager/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ixconn` or Sakis 3g Script.